# Function to show first value in array, if you run it again, show the second value of array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to write a function to get the first value of an array, and if i run the function again, i want to get the second element of an array.
Can someone help me, to increase the Position on the Array, everytime i fire the function?
My Solution doesnt work.

```js
var nextelements = []


/*function SaveIDtoArray(clicked_id)
  {
      nextelements.push(clicked_id);
  }*/


function SaveAndProceed() {
  if (nextelements.length === 1) {
    var x = document.getElementById(nextelements[P]+"_content");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
        P++;
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what is `p` here?

Comment: Simply looping through the array will do what you need.

Comment: Tried to answer as thoroughly as I can, but it's hard to know your exact situation with the code you posted. If you add a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I can adjust my answer to your specific need. Thanks!

Comment: P exists only in the Function

Comment: After giving this more thought I think this might be a case of [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)... what is the exact problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use some global variable and increment it whenever a function is called.

```
data = ['a','b','c']
flag = 0

function displayArray(){
    console.log(data[flag]);
    flag++;
}

displayArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don`t you create copy of an original array and run function on duplicate array. Keep removing first element every time you run function from duplicate array using `duplicate_array.shift()` function of JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want in several ways:

#### Use a global flag:

If what you need is a function that does something special *only* on the first run:

```
let didRun = false;
function SaveAndProceed() {
  if (!didRun) {
    // Code to run the first time
    console.log('running for the first time');
    didRun = true; // remember that the function ran
  } else {
    // Code for the second run and after
    console.log('running again');
  }
}

SaveAndProceed();
// logs 'running for the first time';
SaveAndProceed();
// logs 'running again';
```

> Warning: [using globals is generally harmful](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil)!

#### Higher order functions

In order to not use a global, and protect yourself from unexpected bugs, you can use a higher order function (a function that returns a function) to store the state internally:

```
function runner(firstTime, after) {
  let didRun = false;
  return function () {
    if (!didRun) {
      firstTime();
      didRun = true;
    } else {
      after();
    }
  }
}

const SaveAndProceed = runner(
  function firstTime() { 
    console.log('running for the first time'); 
  },
  function after() { 
    console.log('running again'); 
  }
);

SaveAndProceed();
// logs 'running for the first time';
SaveAndProceed();
// logs 'running again';
```

#### Generators

Another option, if supported, is to use [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator). Generators could be very useful, but may not be supported in the platform(s) that you need to support.

```
function* GenerateSaveAndUpdate() {
   console.log('running for the first time');
   yield firstInvocationResult;
   while(true) {
     yield nextInvocationsResult;
   }
}

const SaveAndProceed = GenerateSaveAndProceed();

SaveAndProceed.next();
// logs 'running for the first time';
SaveAndProceed.next();
// logs 'running again';
```